# Do User Account Controls stick in windows?

Tags: windows, manifest, uac

I was experimenting with an update program called "update.exe" which for the last 10 years just copied changed files from a mapped network drive.  It's been quite a while since Vista was released, but it seems prudent to finally try and tackle UAC.

What I'd like to do is run update.exe in "normal" mode, and if changes are detected restart the program in "elevated" mode.  I think this will work and my question is not about that.  The first step was to run update.exe in non-elevated mode (Windows automatically elevates it because it's called "update.exe")

So I injected a custom manifest file that just ran at the highest available level.   At that level, update.exe was unable to copy any files.  Because of that, I'm trying to be as careful as possible about this and so I rolled back my changes to the manifest and rebuilt the program.

Now, update.exe still does not try to run in elevated mode, even though I reverted the manifest.

So, my question is, is there something in Windows that caches which files are requesting UAC and how do I refresh that so that the program can like it used to?

Comment: Programs running in normal and high integrity have different lists of mapped drives. Which list of mapped drives you want to read? The normal programs' or the list visible to elevated programs?

Comment: It reads the files, I can see their names come across the screen (if I run as admin, I don't see them).   What it doesn't do is actually copy the files.

Comment: Are there any errors?  I wonder if [UAC virtualization](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx) is involved somehow.  Try putting Process Monitor on it.

Comment: @luke yeah, there's no error's I'll bet that's what's just started happening.  I write to a folder in the C:\ - not program files and I don't use Windows Installer or anything fancy.

Comment: Can you install a new copy of Windows, perhaps using Virtual PC, and see whether it tries to elevate update.exe or not?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I can give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Windows cache's the *"elevation needed-ness"*. A reboot will clear it (or changing the filename).